# Golang: How to append pointer to slice to slice?

Tags: pointers, go, slice, dereference

I'm a Golang newbie but I thought I had got the essentials of pointers and references straight, but apparently not:

I have a method that must return a `[]github.Repository`, which is a type from the Github client in go.

The API call returns the results paginated so I must cycle until there's no more results, and add the result of each call to the `allRepos` variable, and return *that*. Here's what I have so far:

```
func (s *inmemService) GetWatchedRepos(ctx context.Context, username string) ([]github.Repository, error) {
    s.mtx.RLock()
    defer s.mtx.RUnlock()

    opt := &github.ListOptions{PerPage: 20}

    var allRepos []github.Repository

    for {
        // repos is of type *[]github.Repository
        repos, resp, err := s.ghClient.Activity.ListWatched(ctx, "", opt)

        if err != nil {
            return []github.Repository{}, err
        }

        // ERROR: Cannot use repos (type []*github.Repository) as type github.Repository
        // but dereferencing it doesn't work, either
        allRepos = append(allRepos, repos...)
        if resp.NextPage == 0 {
            break
        }
        opt.Page = resp.NextPage
    }

    return allRepos, nil

}
```

My question: **how can I append the results of each call and return a result of type `[]github.Repository`?**

Also, why doesn't dereferencing work here? I've tried replacing `allRepos = append(allRepos, repos...)` with `allRepos = append(allRepos, *(repos)...)` but I get this error message:

```
Invalid indirect of (repos) (type []*github.Repository)
```

Comment: Dereferencing should work. Maybe the variable `repos` has another type. Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/UDzaG5z8Pf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, something is not okay here:

You say in the comment that "repos is of type `*[]github.Repository`" but the compiler's error message indicates that repos is of type `[]*Repository`". The compiler is never (except when buggy) wrong.

Note that `*[]github.Repository` and `[]*Repository` are completely different types, especially the second is *not* a slice of Repositories and you *cannot* (really, there is *no* *way*) dereference these pointers during `append()`: You have to write a loop and dereference each slice item and append one by one.

What is strange too: `github.Repository` and `Repository` seem to be two different types one from package github, the other from the current package. Again, you'll have to get that straight too.

Note that there are **no** references in Go. Stop thinking about these immediately: This is a concept from other languages which is not helpful (as inexistent) in Go.

Comment: I had mistyped the error messages. There is a single `Repository` type, and it lives in package `github`.

So the way to do what I want is to dereference each repository in variable `repos` and then append each of those to `allRepos`?

Comment: Yes, of course. To an `[]int` you can append `int` only and not `*int`. As a syntactic sugar you can append `[]int` to `[]int` like `append(orig, fresh...)` but you cannot append `[]**[]***int` to `[]int` just because "deep down there are some ints hidden".

Answer (score 1):

In your example the dereferencing is not correct. You should make it like this:

```
allRepos = append(allRepos, *repos...)
```

Here a simple example with dereferencing a pointer to a slice of string. https://play.golang.org/p/UDzaG5z8Pf

Comment: Still doesn't work... replacing that line with `allRepos = append(allRepos, *repos...)` gives me the same error message (`invalid indirect of repos (type []*github.Repository)`)